# Error:No such property: GradleVersion for class: JetGradlePlugin

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I am getting below error in intellij for a gradle project. I am importing existing gradle project and trying refresh it in gradle window.

```
Error:No such property: GradleVersion for class: JetGradlePlugin
```

Please advise.

Comment: try to clear IDE and gradle cache. then restart IDE. It should work. Also try to compile via terminal, it should work.

Comment: just check
Project Structure => Project => Gradle Version => check your  correct version against android studio here https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had this problem while upgrading to java 11.

I had to downgrade gradle from 5.0 to 4.10.3.
Then I needed to upgrade to the latest version of Intellij Idea.
You'll probably just need to upgrade Intellij.

edit: Downgrading gradle is the fix. The Intellij version didn't matter.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I got this resolved by going to version 4.1 from 5.0. I am using Java 8 though.

Comment: Same here, I just had to downgrade gradle from 5.1.1 to 4.10.3 to resolve it. I didn't have to upgrade IntelliJ though.

Comment: So downgrading is the solution. What if you want to upgrade?

Comment: i tried the same but, android studio throws another error "Minimum support version of gradle is 5.1.1.and current version is 4.6." Please help.

Comment: It CAN be the IntelliJ version: IntelliJ 2017.2 has issues with Gradle 5, so if you have some old IntelliJ (it's now 2019) you DO need to update this

Comment: AS upgrade works for me. if you do need both gradle 5.1.1 and android studio work, please upgrade your android studio to latest version.

Answer (score 13):

You need at least Idea 2017.3 to work with Gradle 5.0+, earlier versions are not compatible because of implicit import being removed [in version 5.0](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html). See related [youtrack ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-182056)

Comment: I upgraded to 2017.3.7, and got this error: `Could not get unknown property 'classesDir' for main classes of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultSourceSetOutput.`. So it didn't work in my particular case, but `gradle v4.10.3` did. Perhaps if I go higher with my IntellJ version I might have better success.

Answer (score 6):

After a couple of days, I found a solution to this.

1)First, find the Gradle version (gradle -v), In my case, Gradle version was 4.1.

2)Then in the android studio change my Gradle version to 4.1
(File --> Project Structure -> Project)

[image]

3)Click ok Button.

that's it :)

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me. 
Go to 'Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle'
And select 'Use local gradle distribution'

Answer (score 2):

I just had to downgrade gradle from 5.1.1 to 4.10.3 to resolve it. However it caused an another error: “cannot resolve symbol R” in Android Studio. I was using gradle 3.3.0. It was the main culprit. Gradle 3.2.1 removed the error.

Answer (score 0):

it's work  downgrade gradle from 5.1.1 to 4.10.3

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as @Khuzi did not provide version information.

Comment: @Khuzi asked for an advise

Comment: Why to downgrade old version? How can I upgrade gradle from 4.10.3 to 5.1.1?

Comment: Exactly, ignoring the problem is not a solution

Answer (score 0):

This was happend to me after i fromat my lap and after installing android 3.1 i tryed to open my projects then this error came

This worked for me:

unstall the android studio > reinstaleled it and updat to the leatest version > upadate gradle