# I implemented VirtualAPK library and getting Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am implemented [VirtualAPK](https://github.com/didi/VirtualAPK) library and failed to build project

My `Project gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
        classpath 'com.didi.virtualapk:gradle:0.9.8.6'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Also I implemented library and applied as per library guide in `Module gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'com.didi.virtualapk.host'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.vspace"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

    implementation 'com.didi.virtualapk:core:0.9.8'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

And after that I am trying to build project and getting Error like():

```
Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
Created classpath snapshot for incremental compilation in 0.024 secs.
[INFO][VAHostPlugin] Used compileClasspath: debug

> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 2.586 secs.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No similar method computeBuildMapping with params [class org.gradle.invocation.DefaultGradle_Decorated] could be found on type class com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

`* Get more help at` https://help.gradle.org

I was also tried to downgrade and upgrade `gradle version` and also tried with old Android Studio 3.0.1 and with 3.4.1. But nothing is working here. So, if any one can help then its surely acceptable.

I also refers [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53600179/8969251) but its can't helped me.

Comment: Nick, compile using 'gradlew assembleDebug --debug --info' and share the log.

Comment: @Ranjan Kumar check my edited description.

Comment: Somebody has raised this issue on virtualapk github and response says to make releasebuild.                                                                                                    
   ./gradlew clean assembleRelease                                                                               https://github.com/didi/VirtualAPK/issues/312

Comment: Build failed yet! I tried!

Answer (score 2):

VirtualApk is doing this.....and computeBuildMapping is not supported(based on error in your post) in gradle 3.4.1.

```
if (project.extensions.extraProperties.get(Constants.GRADLE_3_1_0)) {
                    ImmutableMap<String, String> buildMapping = Reflect.on('com.android.build.gradle.internal.ide.ModelBuilder')
                            .call('computeBuildMapping', project.gradle)
                            .get()
                    compileArtifacts = ArtifactDependencyGraph.getAllArtifacts(
                            applicationVariant.variantData.scope, AndroidArtifacts.ConsumedConfigType.COMPILE_CLASSPATH, null, buildMapping)
                } else {
                    compileArtifacts = ArtifactDependencyGraph.getAllArtifacts(
                            applicationVariant.variantData.scope, AndroidArtifacts.ConsumedConfigType.COMPILE_CLASSPATH, null)
                }
```

so, try building your project with gradle plugin 3.1.0 and gradle version 4.4

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

Comment: So what I need to do?