# React-native/Android Studio: Error:No such property: GradleVersion for class: JetGradlePlugin

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, gradle

I am trying to setup environment for react-native. I have made project using react-native-cli and opened the android directory in Android studio. But stuck in the following error. I have tried following things:

1. Downgrading my gradle from 6.0.1 to 4.1 following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53600179/errorno-such-property-gradleversion-for-class-jetgradleplugin).
2. File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
3. By clearing gradle cache by `gradlew cleanBuildCache`

But nothing is helping. My IDE version is Android Studio 3.0.1

And build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2")

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}
```